# error C3861: 'glewGetContext': identifier not found

Tags: c++, opengl, compilation, glew

Recently, when I tried to compile a project. I got two errors on a line of code:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, internalFormat, dim.x, dim.y, dim.z, 0, inputFormat, type, data);
```

The errors are:

```
Error 2 error C2227: left of '->__glewTexImage3D' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

and

```
Error 3 error C3861: 'glewGetContext': identifier not found
```

I'd like to know does anyone have such error for glew before or have some ideas to solve it?

Comment: Well... are you including the glew header?

Comment: Yes, I think I did and there is no error reported on the include part.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is outdated, but I had this problem today. As warrenm correctly answered there are special steps to bring GLEW MX to work. Unfortunately the link to the documentation only point to the current release of glew (2.1.0), which do not support the MX anymore (since glew 2.0.0). So I describe the steps here which work up to glew 1.13.0:

- Add `GLEW_MX` as preprocessor argument. Optional set `GLEW_STATIC` to use static libs.
- declare this function `GLEWContext* glewGetContext();` and provide it to every code which uses glew.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be using the multi-context feature of GLEW without following the steps detailed here: [Multiple Rendering Contexts (GLEW MX)](http://glew.sourceforge.net/advanced.html).